# Emails to other outlook.com hosted domains bounced with "554 5.4.14 Hop count exceeded"

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

I configured a postfix virtual machine in Azure to act as a relay host for outgoing emails of my Office365-Exchange online hosted domain, because I had to replicate my old on-premise architecture, where there was an Exchange server with a postfix relay. This relay makes some transformation on sender addresses of outgoing emails, following my company policies. Office365-Exchange online is configured with a connector to route all outgoing emails to that Postfix VM on Azure.

On premises setup worked without problems for years. Now that I replicated that setup on Exchange online + Azure postfix VM, the mail flow works without problems, except for recipient domains that are also hosted on outlook.com domains. Every mail sent is bounced with this error:

> host xxx-xxx.mail.protection.outlook.com[X.X.X.X] said: 554 5.4.14 Hop
>       count exceeded - possible mail loop ATTR1
>       [xxx-xxx.prod.protection.outlook.com] (in reply to end of   DATA command)

Do you have any clue?

Edit:  We are still facing the problem, but I have more details:

Not every mail sent to any Office365 domain is bounced with the loop error, only mails sent to domains that have the same *.outlook.com server that we have: searching in postfix logs, i found that our emails are going out from 3 outlook.com servers, with 3 different IP addresses; I found the same and only 3 IP addresses in error logs related to the bounce error.

Here is an example, IP addresses are all fake:

```
mycompany-com.outlook.com [104.1.2.3] -> Postfix relay [54.1.2.3] -> recipient_first-com.outlook.com [104.1.2.3] = Bounce error

mycompany-com.outlook.com [104.1.2.3] -> Postfix relay [54.1.2.3] -> recipient_second-com.outlook.com [104.4.5.6] = mail sent correctly
```

When my outgoing outlook server and the recipient incoming server have the same IP address, the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I found a Microsoft article about your issue for your reference This is likely caused by accepted domain configuration issues or there are misconfigured connectors in your Exchange Online organization in hybrid environments. [Fix email delivery issues for error code 5.4.6 or 5.4.14 in Exchange Online](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/non-delivery-reports-in-exchange-online/fix-error-code-5-4-6-through-5-4-20-in-exchange-online)

Comment: That was indeed an O365 inbound connector configuration issue, we solved with the help of Microsoft support, after a few weeks. They provided me this link that explains O365 message routing: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/office-365-message-attribution/ba-p/749143